# Is it relevant to have a "caller" function for another function (like a setter for a variable)

Tags: c++, header, encapsulation

I'm dealing with some code (of another author that I am unable to contact) that has two functions: Function A and function B.

Function B is declared in an included header file as a public function, but function A is not in the header file. 
Within the corresponding .cpp file both functions, A and B, are defined. However, the only purpose of function B is to call function A (function A being the one not in that header file).

Please help me understand what the point of this is.

My original hypothesis is that function B is used as a "caller" similar to a "setter" function for private variable. I also notice the specific use of the scope resolution operator. Although, my confusion arises because function A is not a private function.

```
//     ~~~~ header file:

class theClass {

public:
    long functionB(parameters);

private:
    // empty
};



//     ~~~~ .cpp file:

#include "theClass.h"


long functionA(parameters)
{
relevant_statements // but trivial to my question

return(relevant_variable);
};


long theClass::functionB(parameters)
{
return(functionA(parameters));
};
```

There is no error in compilation of the code so please ignore any syntax errors in my pseudo code. My question regards to function encapsulation and programmer convention.

Comment: FWIW, I see no point to this. - Code may have evolved into its present state without being properly reviewed.

Comment: Please show the code.

Comment: if the real code is similar to the one you show here, then this has nothing to do with setters. It is merely a unnecessary indirection. Is `functionA` called also in different places in the source file?

Comment: `long theClass::functionB(parameters);` isn't legal C++ (remove the qualifier).

Comment: No, this is the only call to functionA. Would this be more relevant if functionA were declared in the header file as a private function?

Comment: My guess is that `functionA` used to be - or was planned to be - called in more than one place. It could also be left over from before the code was turned into a class, and there can be numerous other reasons.

Comment: Thank you for the reassurance and insight.

Comment: it may also reduce coupling with internal members of the class.

Comment: Such a `functionA` ought to have internal linkage to avoid accidentally colliding with a helper in another file.